# Generic xslt that transform xml structure in html list

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I need a generic xslt that transform xml to an html list.

Example xml snippet:

```
<person>
  <firstname>A</firstname>
  <lastname>B</lastname>
  <address>
   <city>C</city>
   <street>S</street>
  </address>
</person>
```

The output should be

```
<ul>
    <li>person
        <ul>
            <li>firstname: A</li>
            <li>lastname: B</li>
            <li>address
            <ul>
                <li>city: C</li>
                <li>street: S</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The source xml is generated at runtime an will not always have this structure. So the tag names can be different. Therfore the xslt has to be generic.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="*">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]"> 
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', .)"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```